# Why is my Modal not popping up after boolean change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-modal

I am having this issue with a project using Vue 2.6.12. The goal is to open "add-metric" modal when the user closes "close-metric" modal with an option or multi-options selected. These 2 modals are separate components that are a child to the parent component. I am able to close the "close-metric" modal, pass the data into the parent component, flip a boolean called "add" to "true" on the parent component to signal "add-metric" modal to open. However,the "add-metric" modal doesn't open with the :if="add" even when the boolean is true. No error pops up at all.

Here is the "Close-metric" modal Code which builds the request to send over to the Parent Component.

```
    addProjectMetric(projectMetricRequest) {
      this.errors = [];

      let request = {
        projectMetricId: this.$helpers.generateUUID(),
        projectMetricGroupId: this.projectMetric.projectMetricGroupId,
        projectId: this.projectId,
        type: projectMetricRequest.resolutionReason,
        name: projectMetricRequest.name,
        status: "Open",
        tags: projectMetricRequest.tags,
        description: projectMetricRequest.description,
        dateCreated: projectMetricRequest.dateResolved,
        dateIdentified: projectMetricRequest.dateResolved,
        createdBy: [projectMetricRequest.createdBy],
        assignedToUsers: this.projectMetric.assignedToUsers,
        identifiedByRole: projectMetricRequest.identifiedByRole,
        timeSaved: projectMetricRequest.timeSaved,
        costSaved: projectMetricRequest.costSaved,
        participants: projectMetricRequest.participants,
      };
        this.addProjectMetricFromParent(request);
      //request = this.applyOverrides(request);
    },
  addProjectMetricFromParent(projectMetric) {
        this.$emit('add-Resolution-Metric', projectMetric)
        this.cancel();
    },
    cancel() {
      this.reset();
      this.hide();
    },
    reset() {
      this.errors = [];
      // this.form = this.newForm();
      this.form = null;
    },
hide() {
      this.showCloseModal = false;
    },
```

Here is the parent page html with the two components I am closing and trying to open

```
<CloseProjectMetricModal
          v-if="item.action === 'Close'"
          :ref="`close-${slugify(addNewText)}-modal`"
          :projectId="$route.params.id"
          :title="`Close &quot;${limitText(currentMetric)}&quot;`"
          mode="Close"
          :projectMetric="currentMetric"
          :possibleAssignees="item.possibleAssignees"
          :addTypes="item.addTypes"
          :meetingId="$route.params.meetingId"
          @add-Resolution-Metric="openAddModal($event)"
          @submit="closeProjectMetricSubmit(item)"
        />
<addProjectMetricModal
      v-if="add"
      :ref="`add-project-metric-reason-modal`"
      :projectId="$route.params.id"
      :title="'Add New Metric '"
      :mode="'Add'"
      :projectMetric="viewingNewMetric"
      :possibleAssignees="item.possibleAssignees"
      :presetTags="projectSummary.project.presetTags"
      :meetingId="$route.params.meetingId"
      @submit="addProjectMetricReasonSubmit()">
      </addProjectMetricModal>
```

Here is the code on the Parent component which should be allowing the "add-metric" modal to be seen.

```
 props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    addNewText: {
      type: String,
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    length: {
      type: Number,
      default: 6,
    },
    projectSummary: {
      type: Object,
    },
    projectTags: {
      type: Array,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentMetric: null,
      newProjectMetric: null,
      add : false,
    };
  },
 openAddModal(newMetric) {
      this.newProjectMetric = newMetric;
      console.log(this.newProjectMetric)
      console.log("hit")
      //this.closeProjectMetricSubmit();
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.add = true;
      // let modal =  document.getElementById(this.metricReason)
      // modal.show();
      // let ref = `add-project-metric-reason-modal`;
      // this.$refs[ref].show();
      });
    },
```

Is there something I am missing or not understanding fully with modals? For quick example here are the HTML for the "Close-metric" and "Add-metric" modal.

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    :title="title"
    v-model="showCloseModal"
    :ok-disabled="editDisabled"
    @ok.prevent="submit"
    size="lg"
    @cancel.prevent="cancel"
  >
    <b-form v-if="form" @submit.prevent>
      <b-form-group
        v-if="isPresent('name')"
        :label="getTitle('name', 'Title')"
        label-for="project-metric-name"
        invalid-feedback="Please fill out this field"
      >
        <b-form-input
          id="project-metric-name"
          v-model.trim="form.name"
          required
          :disabled="editDisabled"
          :autofocus="!showCloseFields"
          maxlength="100"
          :state="
            errors.length == 0
              ? null
              : errors.length == 0
              ? null
              : form.name.length > 0
          "
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
  
            <!-- This is for only the Closed Section -->
      <b-row  v-if="!this.meetingId == '' && this.mode=='Close'">
        <b-col cols="4" v-if="isPresent('resolutionReason')">
          <b-form-group
            :label="getTitle('resolutionReason', 'Resolution Reason')"
            label-for="project-metric-resolution-reason"
          >
            <multiselect
              v-model="projectMetricResolutions"
              :options="otherMetricResolutions"
              :multiple="true"
              :close-on-select="false"
              :clear-on-select="false"
              :preserve-search="true"
              placeholder="Pick Resolution Reason"
              label="name"
              track-by="name"
              :preselect-first="false"
              class="normalFontSize"
              :show-labels="false"
            >
              <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, isOpen }"
                ><span
                  class="multiselect__single"
                  v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen"
                  >{{ values.length }} options selected</span
                ></template
              >
            </multiselect>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
        <b-col v-if="isPresent('resolutionLevel')">
          <b-form-group
            :label="getTitle('resolutionLevel', 'Resolution Level')"
            label-for="project-metric-resolution-level"
          >
            <b-form-select
              id="project-metric-resolution-level"
              :disabled="editDisabled"
              v-model="form.resolutionLevel"
            >
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </b-form-select>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
            <!-- This is where the Closed Section Ends -->
    </b-form>
    <MessageBlock :messages="errors"></MessageBlock>
    <template v-slot:modal-ok>
      <div>
        <b-spinner v-if="sending" small label="Spinning" />
        <div v-else-if="mode === 'Close'">Close</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>
export default {
  name: "CloseProjectMetricModal",
  mixins: [pmMixin],
  components: { Multiselect },
  props: {
    title: { type: String, default: "Edit Action Item" },
    mode: { type: String, default: "Edit" },
    projectMetric: { type: Object },
    projectId: String,
    possibleAssignees: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
    addTypes: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        "Risk",
        "Issue",
        "Efficiency",
        "Innovation",
        "Partnership",
        "Sustainability",
      ],
    },
    dataTemplate: Object,
    presetTags: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
    meetingId: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      errors: [],
      showCloseModal: false,
      sending: false,
      returnToView: false,
      form: null,
      description: "",
      filterCriteria: "",
      projectMetricResolutions: [],
      otherMetricResolutions: [
        { name: "Innovation", type: "Innovation" },
        { name: "Efficiency", type: "Efficiency" },
        { name: "Partnership", type: "Partnership" },
        { name: "Sustainability", type: "Sustainability" },
      ],
      allResolutionReason: "",
      todaysNewDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      showAddModal: false,
    };
  },
}
```

AddMetricModal

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    :title="title"
    v-model="showModal"
    :ok-disabled="editDisabled"
    @ok.prevent="submit"
    size="lg"
    @cancel.prevent="cancel"
  >
    <b-form v-if="form" @submit.prevent>
      <b-form-group
        v-if="isPresent('name')"
        :label="getTitle('name', 'Title')"
        label-for="project-metric-name"
        invalid-feedback="Please fill out this field"
      >
        <b-form-input
          id="project-metric-name"
          v-model.trim="form.name"
          required
          :disabled="editDisabled"
          :autofocus="!showCloseFields"
          maxlength="100"
          :state="
            errors.length == 0
              ? null
              : errors.length == 0
              ? null
              : form.name.length > 0
          "
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group
        v-if="isPresent('description')"
        :label="getTitle('description')"
        label-for="project-metric-description"
      >
        <b-form-textarea
          id="project-metric-description"
          v-model.trim="form.description"
          :disabled="editDisabled"
          maxlength="1000"
          rows="3"
        ></b-form-textarea>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-row>
        <b-col v-if="isPresent('type')">
          <b-form-group
            :label="getTitle('type')"
            label-for="project-metric-type"
          >
            <div class="select-wrapper">
              <b-form-select
                id="project-metric-type"
                :disabled="editDisabled"
                v-model="form.type"
                :options="getTypeOptions"
              ></b-form-select>
            </div>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <b-button
            v-for="(t, i) in unselectedTags"
            :key="i"
            class="mr-1 button-tag"
            @click="addTag(t)"
          >
            {{ t }}
          </b-button>
          <b-form-group
            v-if="isPresent('tags')"
            :label="getTitle('tags')"
            label-for="project-metric-tags"
          >
            <b-form-tags
              id="project-metric-tags"
              v-model.trim="form.tags"
              separator=","
              add-button-variant="secondary"
              :disabled="editDisabled"
            ></b-form-tags>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-form>
    <MessageBlock :messages="errors"></MessageBlock>
    <template v-slot:modal-ok>
      <div>
        <b-spinner v-if="sending" small label="Spinning" />
        <div v-else-if="mode === 'Add'">Add</div>
        <div v-else-if="mode === 'Edit'">Save</div>
        <div v-else-if="mode === 'Close'">Close</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>

import axios from "axios";
import pmMixin from "@/mixins/project-metric-mixin.js";
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {
  name: "EditProjectMetricModal",
  mixins: [pmMixin],
  components: { Multiselect },
  props: {
    title: { type: String, default: "Edit Action Item" },
    mode: { type: String, default: "Edit" },
    projectMetric: { type: Object },
    projectId: String,
    possibleAssignees: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
    addTypes: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        "Risk",
        "Issue",
        "Efficiency",
        "Innovation",
        "Partnership",
        "Sustainability",
      ],
    },
    dataTemplate: Object,
    presetTags: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
    meetingId: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      errors: [],
      showModal: false,
      sending: false,
      returnToView: false,
      form: null,
      description: "",
      filterCriteria: "",
      uselessArray: [],
      projectMetricResolutions: [],
      otherMetricResolutions: [
        { name: "Innovation", type: "Innovation" },
        { name: "Efficiency", type: "Efficiency" },
        { name: "Partnership", type: "Partnership" },
        { name: "Sustainability", type: "Sustainability" },
      ],
      allResolutionReason: "",
      todaysNewDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    };
  },
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Did you define "add" in a component state? I can't find it. There is an "allowAdd"

Comment: @coder My apologies, I wasn't trying to give the code exactly as is. "allowAdd" is "add", I forgot to change that section. I just changed it now, thanks for letting me know